# Filling a vector with a varying amount of variables

Tags: python, arrays, variables

Hey currently I'm trying to program a quadratic programming algorithm with Python.

**My goal:**
I want to program a function where the given parameters are one vector c, and a matrix G. They are connected through the function Phi = 0.5 *(x^T * G * x) + c^T *x (x^T in this context means vector x transposed). The goal of the function is to find a vector x so that the function Phi is minimized. In order to do that, I need to perform some algebraic calculations (multiplication, transposing and deriving the gradient of the function Phi).

My problem: But I'm struggling with creating a vector which indicates the dimensions of the problem. I am trying to create a vector x = [x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_N] which containts N elements. N varies. The elements 'x_N' should be variables (since I want to compute them later on, but I need them 'beforehand' to calculate e.g. the gradient).

My code so far: ('NoE'... is equal to N+1, thats why Im substracting 1 in my while statement)

```
 #filling the x-vector according to the dimension of the given problem
    temp_2 = 0
    while temp_2 <= (NoE-1):   
        x[temp_2]= 'x_' + temp_2
        print(x)
```

**The previous answer just helped me partially:**
The only problem I am encountering now, is that those are all strings and I cant perform any kind of mathematical operation with them (like multiplying them with a matrix). Do you know any fix how I can still do it with strings?

Or do you think I could use the sympy library (which would help me with future calculations)?

**Im open to every suggestion of solving this, since I dont have a lot of experience in programming generally**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an [x y problem](https://xyproblem.info/), because I don't understand how you are going to initialize those variables. If you provide more context I will update my answer.

If you want to have your list to contain variables or "symbols" on which you do algebraic operations, then the standard library doesn't have that, but you can use [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```py
import sympy
from sympy import symbols

### First we initialize some Symbol objects

# this does essentially what you were doing in the question, but in one line
# see list comprehensions* 
symbol_names = [f'x_{i}' for i in range(NoE-1)]

# then we make them become 'Symbols'
x = symbols(symbol_names)

### Next we can do stuff with them:

# multiply the first two
expr = x[0] * x[1]
print(expr)  # x_0*x_1

# evaluate the expression `expr` with x_0=3, x_1=2
res = expr.evalf(subs={'x_0':3, 'x_1':2})
print(res)  # 6.00000
```

Even though the `sympy` code above answer your question as it is, I don't think that it's the best solution to the problem you were describing.

For example you could just have a `list` called `x` and then you populate it with elements

```py
x = []
for i in range(NoE-1):
    x.append(
        float(input(f'insert value x_{i}'))
    )
```

This way `x` will have all the inputted elements and you can access them via `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and so on.

---

* [docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: I added some more information in my question in case you want to take another look at it.

Comment: Sounds like you should just initialize a list `x` and access its values via `x[0]`, `x[1]` etc... Which is what I wrote. You can try writing up a tentative code and then ask for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own type (class) and implement any logic you want there:

```py
class Vector(int):
    def __new__(cls, name: str, number: int):
        created_object = super().__new__(cls, number)
        return created_object

    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name 
        self.number = number
        # print(f'{name} is called with number={number}')
    
    # if ypu want to get the same type after math operation
    # you'll have to implement all magics like so
    ## otherwise comment it and you'll get the result of int type on multiplying
    def __mul__(self, other):
            return Vector("".join([self.name, "*",other.name]), self.number * other.number)
            
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name}: {self.number}'

v1 = Vector("v1", 3)
v2 = Vector("v2", 4)

print(v1)
print(v2)

print(v1*v2)

# int result as it is not implemented in class
v3 = v1 + v2
print(v3)


v = [ Vector(f"v_{x}", x+1) for x in range(0,2)]

print(v)

t = [mv * v1 for mv in v]

print(t)
```